# How to replace outing call number ? CallRedirectionService is not valid

Tags: java, android

How to replace outing call number?

```
class RedirectionService extends CallRedirectionService {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceCall(
            @NonNull Uri handle,
            @NonNull PhoneAccountHandle initialPhoneAccount,
            boolean allowInteractiveResponse
    ) {

        // Determine if the call should proceed, be redirected, or cancelled.
        // Your app should implement this logic to determine the redirection.

        boolean callShouldProceed = false;
        boolean callShouldRedirect = true;
        if (callShouldProceed) {
            placeCallUnmodified();
        } else if (callShouldRedirect) {
            handle = Uri.parse("911"); //Dail this phone number when outing call.

            redirectCall(handle, initialPhoneAccount, true);
        } else {
            cancelCall();
        }
```

It happens:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcWee.png)

Thank you for your help.